# django-admin-tools markup problems

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I try to install admin-tools for django.
I've got strange css and it's evident that something is wrong. But what? Google and css analyzing didn't help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqjtf.png)

Thanks!

**Update and solution:**

I did the homework and solved the problem. What I got:

When I add admin-tools.theming, base.css is missing. The reason is wrong path. Instead of /static/admin/css/base.css it is /admin-media/css/base.css. "admin-media" was my admin media prefix. I left it when I tried to set up my apache server and then I changed static path.

So, it was necessary only to define right admin media prefix as "/static/admin/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) is your friend. Install it in Firefox (or use Firebug Lite in Chrome). Go to your page, hit F12, click the Element Selection Tool (a blue box with an arrow pointing into it in the upper right of the Firebug pane), then click on the offending item. On the left you will see all sorts of good style info including file and line number, and (if you scroll down) all of the style rules that were *overridden* by one file or another.

Enlightenment soon follows.

If you still have problems, update your question with a link to the live page with the problem so that we can go look at it (screenshots are dead pixels).

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, but digging deep into those issues i found out that the 'django-admin-tools' version which i used is not compatible with the django version (1.4).  That means the django-admin-tools have undergone many changes to accommodate modifications made in Django.  Since there is no package created for the latest source code of django-admin-tools, usage of 'easy_install' and 'pip' will always fetch the older version.

So the solution is to download the latest source code from here

https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/downloads

https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/get/tip.zip

and installing them by using `'setup.py install'` command.